# pyenv: no such command `virtualenv'

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm following a [tutorial](https://illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/28/installing-pytorch-on-ubuntu-20.html) on setting up torch on ubuntu 20.04 one line requires to setup `pyenv` which is like virtualenv for python so I can have multiple versions of python running. A bit unnecessary but it's a learning process and a good chance to learn of another new tool I might use another day.

So this command after successfully setting up pyenv fails

```
sam@sam:~/torch$ pyenv virtualenv 3.8.2 torch
pyenv: no such command `virtualenv'
```

so to cover my basics I already have virtualenv installed as shown here

```
sam@sam:~/torch$ virtualenv
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--clear-app-data] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--creator {builtin,cpython3-posix,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed]
                [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--download | --no-download] [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--progress version] [--retrying version] [--urllib3 version]
                [--pep517 version] [--colorama version] [--CacheControl version] [--certifi version] [--requests version] [--contextlib2 version] [--appdirs version] [--chardet version] [--pytoml version] [--html5lib version]
                [--lockfile version] [--six version] [--webencodings version] [--pyparsing version] [--setuptools version] [--packaging version] [--wheel version] [--ipaddr version] [--idna version] [--pip version] [--distro version]
                [--pkg_resources version] [--distlib version] [--msgpack version] [--no-progress] [--no-retrying] [--no-urllib3] [--no-pep517] [--no-colorama] [--no-CacheControl] [--no-certifi] [--no-requests] [--no-contextlib2]
                [--no-appdirs] [--no-chardet] [--no-pytoml] [--no-html5lib] [--no-lockfile] [--no-six] [--no-webencodings] [--no-pyparsing] [--no-setuptools] [--no-packaging] [--no-wheel] [--no-ipaddr] [--no-idna] [--no-pip] [--no-distro]
                [--no-pkg_resources] [--no-distlib] [--no-msgpack] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
                dest
virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest
```

and pyenv is installed as shown here

```
sam@sam:~/torch$ pyenv
pyenv 1.2.19-1-gece59ca8
Usage: pyenv <command> [<args>]

Some useful pyenv commands are:
commands    List all available pyenv commands
exec        Run an executable with the selected Python version
global      Set or show the global Python version(s)
help        Display help for a command
hooks       List hook scripts for a given pyenv command
init        Configure the shell environment for pyenv
install     Install a Python version using python-build
local       Set or show the local application-specific Python version(s)
prefix      Display prefix for a Python version
rehash      Rehash pyenv shims (run this after installing executables)
root        Display the root directory where versions and shims are kept
shell       Set or show the shell-specific Python version
shims       List existing pyenv shims
uninstall   Uninstall a specific Python version
--version   Display the version of pyenv
version     Show the current Python version(s) and its origin
version-file   Detect the file that sets the current pyenv version
version-name   Show the current Python version
version-origin   Explain how the current Python version is set
versions    List all Python versions available to pyenv
whence      List all Python versions that contain the given executable
which       Display the full path to an executable

See `pyenv help <command>' for information on a specific command.
For full documentation, see: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme
```

Comment: the tutorial assumes you have `pyenv-virtualenv` installed. `pyenv virtualenv` command will only work if you have `pyenv-virtualenv` installed. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: Looks like you installed `pyenv` but forgot to also install the other dependency `pyenv-virtualenv`. Voting to close as trivial. The third-party package `virtualenv` is unnecessary and irrelevant.

Comment: you can use my solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534632/12075605

Comment: Running `pip install pyenv-virtualenv` gives me this error:

    `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyenv-virtualenv
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyenv-virtualenv`

With python 3.8.7 and pip 21.0.1

Answer (score 79):

This was discussed in the thread under your comment but you need pyenv-virtualenv.

How to download: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Easy way is via homebrew on mac `brew install pyenv-virtualenv`