# pipenv can't install packages and throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am a newbie to python. I have just installed Python and Pip.
I need to install some packages for a personal project.
I created a virtual environment using `$ pipenv shell`.
I then ran `$ pipenv install dlib`.
But I received the following error:

```
Error text:
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\samya\.virtualenvs\py_img_recog-DAsXOW1h\Scripts\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\samya\\.virtualenvs\\py_img_recog-DAsXOW1h\\Scripts\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\samya\\.virtualenvs\\py_img_recog-DAsXOW1h\\Scripts\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\samya\\.virtualenvs\\py_img_recog-DAsXOW1h\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'c:\\users\\samya\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000042ec (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[   =] Installing dlib...
Installation Failed
```

I am running Python 3.8.3 and Pip 20.1.1 on Windows 10 x64 bit system.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this means your pip command path is not set in the path variables of system

You can try doing the following:

- go to This Pc>properties>Advanced Settings>environment variables
- ..then click new
- ..then select the path where your python pip command is available
- .. and simply give it a name python38 thats it
- then it will create your venv

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use virtual environment you can use virtualenv package in python work with this package is easy

you can install this package with

```
python[version] -m pip install virtualenv
```

or use

```
pip[version] install virtualenv
```

then

go to path you want in your system and use this code in your windows cmd

```
virtualenv [name_of_your_folder]
```

then with cd command go to the folder created and open Scripst folder

then use this

```
activate.bat
```

By following these steps, you will enter the Python virtual environment on your system

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer... Your method works! But can you tell me what caused the error and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: Note that in the above error, wrote that I could not find such module as 'encoding', maybe you did not install the package correctly or you installed the old versions of that package, we have this error in virtualenv too, you can remove package and install again or if you have python2, python3.7 and python3.8 with together your remove all of them and install one of them, i think this solution mabye solve this problem